# Entity Framework Seed method exception

Tags: entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I am using Entity Framework 6 with an MVC5 webapi2 project against an Oracle database.

I am trying to add some ApplicationRoles in the Seed method, but when I execute update-database I get this exception:

> Running Seed method.
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type is not resolved for member 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException,Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342'.
>      at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
>   Type is not resolved for member 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException,Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342'.

My code in the Seed method:

```
var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);

if (!context.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "USER"))
{
    var role = new IdentityRole("USER");
    roleManager.Create(role);
}
```

`update-database` is creating my tables without any problem, it's just the Seed method which has a problem.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what the problem could be please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Installing Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll to GAC resolved my issue. If you installed Oracle Client or Oracle Database on your machine that might be the cause.

```
C:\Windows\system32>cd E:\smn\packages\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.12.1.021\lib\net40

C:\Windows\system32>e:

E:\smn\packages\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.12.1.021\lib\net40>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\gacutil.exe" /i Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll
Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.33440
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Assembly successfully added to the cache
```

Comment: Note, you don't need to use the gacutil path shown above (especially those that don't have the sdk shown). If you have VS installed, simply use the developer prompt. `gacutil` is on path.